# Does a query occur through dirty checking even if the same value is inserted into the corresponding column?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I'm configuring an entity update method, and I'm curious what the result will be if I put the same value in the same column as before and perform dirty checking.

```java
public class Member extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "member_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private MBTI mbti;

    @Column
    private Boolean isDeleted;

    @Column
    private String statusMessage;

    @Column
    private String avatar;

    public static Member toEntity(MemberRequestDto.signup requestDto) {
        return Member.builder()
            .email(requestDto.getEmail())
            .password(requestDto.getPassword())
            .username(requestDto.getUsername())
            .mbti(requestDto.getMbti())
            .statusMessage(requestDto.getStatusMessage())
            .isDeleted(false)
            .build();
    }

    public void update(MemberRequestDto.update requestDto) {
        this.password = requestDto.getPassword();
        this.username = requestDto.getUsername();
        this.mbti = requestDto.getMbti();
        this.statusMessage = requestDto.getStatusMessage();
    }

    public void uploadAvatar(String url) {
        this.avatar = url;
    }
}
```

In update method, Does the query occur if the column value of requestdto is already the same as the entity?

Comment: What dirty checking are you performing exactly? Are you maybe asking about JPA EntityManager merge behavior? if there is no update, there should be no update statement issued to the database, but entirely depends on factors you haven't shown or given us - you are better off testing it and looking at the SQL generated as what happens can be provider (and setting) specific